# Unity container register object that receive container in constructor

Tags: c#, unity-container, containers, ioc-container

I have a container implemented in unity 2.0 and DI.
I have a singleton factory class that i register in the container.
How can I register it if one of its constructor parameters are IContainer ?
What is the technique to do so ? To register singelton object that consumes the container in the constructor.

Thanks

Comment: I would be surprised if  that was supported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply register the container into itself:

```cs
container.RegisterInstance<IUnityContainer>(container);
```

Note however that you should ***ONLY*** inject the container into classes that are part of your [composition root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/); part of the infrastructure.